# PHP Fpm process is killing my website: process is blocked with status D

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, nginx

After days of searching in the web, Stack Overflow, Google,. Everywhere, I can not understand what happens to PHP-fpm after hours of working normally.

**Description of the problem:**

I have an Ubuntu 16.04 VPS where I have installed PHP-FPM and Nginx and a small redis-server to store sessions. I have 4 websites running under PHP-fpm. All websites are good, just one of them has this problem.

**PHP-FPM communicate with Nginx using sockets.**

After hours working properly, suddenly PHP-FPM processes did not work and have status **D** when I run htop command. Here is a screenshot of the output of the htop command:

[image: demonstration]

After searching in the internet, I got that status D means that process is waiting for resource.

I have added more memory for MySQL Server but nothing happens. MySQL server is fine when I execute commands from workbench or any other application.

**Perhaps, it's a memory problem?**

I added memory for VPS and it now it runs with 6 GB of memory (most of memory is not used). PHP-FPM continue having status D after hours of running.

**Perhaps it's related to opened file descriptors?**

I changed the number of opened files descriptor to 2097152 which is a very big number. I continue getting the same problem.

**Perhaps, it's a socket problem or Linux config problem?**

I have increased the most Linux configuration parameters like this:

```
# Increase size of file handles and inode cache
fs.file-max = 2097152

# unix sockets accept by default 127 connections.
net.core.somaxconn = 4096

vm.swappiness = 0
vm.vfs_cache_pressure = 50

#Needed by redis
vm.overcommit_memory = 1

#
# 16MB per socket - which sounds like a lot, but will virtually never
# consume that much.
#
net.core.rmem_max = 16777216
net.core.wmem_max = 16777216

# Increase the number of outstanding syn requests allowed.
# c.f. The use of syncookies.
net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog = 8192
```

But I continue having the same problem. This is what I get in nginx log:

```
2016/07/17 22:57:30 [alert] 1885#1885: *59394 open socket #156 left in connection 117
2016/07/17 22:57:30 [alert] 1885#1885: *59341 open socket #107 left in connection 118
2016/07/17 22:57:30 [alert] 1885#1885: *59385 open socket #148 left in connection 119
2016/07/17 22:57:30 [alert] 1885#1885: *59392 open socket #154 left in connection 121
```

I have tried most of recommanded solutions found in the web, but without success.

I have changed these parameters in PHP-fpm.conf.

```
emergency_restart_threshold = 30
emergency_restart_interval = 180
process_control_timeout = 30
```

Here is PHP-fpm config of the pool:

```
pm = ondemand
pm.max_children = 30
pm.process_idle_timeout = 10s;
pm.max_requests = 500
```

This is my nginx site config:

```
fastcgi_buffers 256 16k;
fastcgi_max_temp_file_size 0;

    location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm-mysite.com.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
        internal;
    }
```

Nginx Global config:

```
worker_processes 2;
worker_rlimit_nofile 100000;

pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections 1024;
        multi_accept on;
}
```

**Last thing**: Before 2 weeks, I was running Ubuntu 14.04 and I have upgraded my server to Ubuntu 16.04 and I have a lot of issues. But this one, I can not understand exactly the origin of this problem.

I'm using Ocache to cache code and I have increased all parameters to get more memory and website works fine and cache is never full.

I have already restarted the server a lot of times to apply configuration.

Disc: 50% full. I have a lot of space.

Note that when PHP-fpm process are blocked, I have restarted the whole service and few seconds later, I got the same problem. I did same thing for nginx and I got the same problem. **The only way to make website work is to restart the whole system**.

Please, any help is welcome!

Comment: Let's take a step back and figure this out holistically.  Remove all traffic from the server.  Hit a test page with nothing but `<?php phpinfo();` in it.  Do you get a response?  Then, hit it a few hundred times.  Still getting responses?  Are processes stacking up?  If that works fine, now add something that loads sessions.  Last time I had a problem like this, there was locking around session data in Redis.  The third-party component I was using was buggy, so I just spent an afternoon and rewrote it.  But, I don't know if that's your problem here.  Start with the basics, debug from there.

Comment: Thanks @Brad, but i can not stop the server, because it's online :(

I think that problem is related to number of opened sockets as nginx logs suggest. but i have increased the number to 4096 and i got the same problem. I have a Varnish in front of nginx so not all traffic is sent to php-fpm.

Comment: You mentioned you have other servers?  Can't you drain traffic from this one and balance across the others temporarily?  Can you build a new server to experiment with, and then cut traffic over to it when you have it working?

Comment: No backup servers, just one for Mysql, one application (php-fpm, nginx, redis) and one for varnish. Perhaps, the problem comes from the worker_rlimit_nofile in nginx config. I changed the default one to 100000. I'm tracking this way.

Comment: I have changed the nginx max open files in /etc/security/limits.conf like this:

nginx       soft    nofile   65535
nginx       hard    nofile   65535

And i have set the same thing for worker_rlimit_nofile (65535). And i will wait to see what will happen next day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After days of looking for a solution, the problem was not related to Linux inodes, not related to memory and not related to sockets...

It's related to application code.

I use Symfony2 Framework, and for some reasons, i had changed the parameter "auto_generate_proxy_classes" to true. And i have pushed the code to production.

When auto_generate_proxy_classes is set to true, Doctrine will check all proxies classes and regenerate them each request. So when i got a lot of requests, php-fpm processes will regenerate theses classes in the same time. So process were blocked until other process finish code generation.

**Solution:**

instead of:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        ....
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: true.
```

Put the default Symfony2 config:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        ....
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
```

Comment: I'm getting this on a laravel application, any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and tried tweaking most of the above parameters you mentioned.  Not running Symfony, just plain PHP 5.6 on Ubuntu 16.04 with nginx/php-fpm.

The server had been running fine for weeks and suddenly it quit responding to web requests.  I was getting lots of "open socket #nnn left in connection" messages in the /var/log/nginx/error.log and "server reached pm.max_children setting" messages in /var/log/php5.6-fpm.log

It was running on a virtual server at Profitbricks with an AMD processor.  After multiple restarts and reboots and several hours without success, I had run out of ideas and finally called Profitbricks support to see if there were any hardware or network issues.  None were reported, but they suggested changing the processor type from AMD to Intel Xeon.

After I changed to the XEON processor, the server rebooted and everything worked fine.

I'm still not sure of what caused the problem (and it may not be possible to switch processors on many VPS), but hopefully this solution may be helpful to someone.